# Expected Value of Greatest Integer Random Variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|},\;\; -\infty<x<\infty.
\end{equation}
What is expected value of $\lfloor X \rfloor$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
E( \lfloor X \rfloor),
\end{equation}
where $\lfloor X \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer of $X$.

Comment: @Chinny84 greatest integer command is not working properly here. So, I just denote by some other notation but I have defined this notation.

Comment: how far have you got?  could you work out the expected value without the greatest integer part, using integration?

Comment: find prob of greatest integer being n, then do infinite summation of nP(N = n) to get average - the summation is different for n<0 and n>=0

Comment: @Cato could you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define, for ease of notation, $Z=\lfloor X \rfloor$.

To get the expectation, let's first find the distribution law of $Z$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Then $P(Z=n)=P(n\leq X < n+1)=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}dx=\frac{e-1}{2e^{n+1}}$.

Because of the symmetry of the function $\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$ around $0$, we have that $P(Z=-n-1)=P(-n-1\leq X<-n)=P(n\leq X < n+1)=P(Z=n)$.

Now we can simply calculate the expectation:
\begin{align}
E(Z) &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}kP(Z=k)\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}nP(Z=n)+\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{-1}kP(Z=k)\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}nP(Z=n)+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-n-1)P(Z=-n-1)\\
&= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}nP(Z=n)+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-n-1)P(Z=n)\\
&= -\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{e-1}{2e^{n+1}} = \frac{1-e}{2e}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{e}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

In fact the answer is $- 1/2$ for any density function which is symmetric about zero, and has finite expectation.  The point is that 
$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor = -1$ for every non-integer $x$.
So $E \lfloor X \rfloor + E \lfloor -X \rfloor = -1$ given finite expectation, and then (given symmetry) $E \lfloor -X \rfloor = E \lfloor X \rfloor $.